# Unable to run the program using get() function

Tags: c++

I have written a program that takes `name` and `dessert` as input and than output it. I want to use the `get()` function for this operation. I am programming in Eclipse Mars C++ with MinGW compiler. When I try to run the program a warning message pops up saying that error exists in the program although it doesn't show where the error is and nothing happens after that. Take a look at my code below-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main() {
 const int ArSize=15;
 char name[ArSize];
 char dessert[ArSize];

 cin.get(name, ArSize); // read first line
 cin.get(); // read newline
 cin.get(dessert, ArSize); // read second line
 cin.get(); // read newline

 cout<<name<<endl<<dessert;

 return 0;
}
```

What could be the error. Is there some fault in the compiler or I am doing something wrong. I am reading from the book C++ Primer with the almost same code. The image of which is [image: here] .

Comment: Rather use the operator `>>` with `cin` and `std::string`, not raw arrays.

Comment: I am learning from the book C++ Primer in which the code is exact same, and it is mentioned that there should be an output

Comment: Well, your code [works here](http://ideone.com/J6K2tP). What are your particular errors, please mention these in your question verbatim.

Comment: I have added the code from the book as image. When I click on run a warning message pops out saying that `Errors exist in required project.Continue launch?` although it doesn't show any error in the code. Maybe my compiler have some fault.

Comment: Please post a [MCVE] including all of your error messages verbatim. I'd suspect you have compiler error messages. Also make clear which compiler and IDE was used.

Comment: @Paras, there is a compiler output window and extracted errors window. Get the error from there.

Comment: That's the problem there are no error messages being shown but when I try to run it nothing happens.

Comment: @Paras, the errors should normally be also marked in the source itself (with red underlines and little stop signs in the left margin). You'd have to be really blind to miss them, so I suppose they are not there, which might mean it is a _linker_ error, because those are not related for specific line in the source and so can't be marked there.

Comment: @Paras, I am absolutely certain the messages are there when you "Build" it. You may have the relevant window hidden and have to show it via menu (if you didn't "Build" it, that might be the problem).

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing, but `std::endl` won't be defined unless you also have `#include <iomanip>`. But don't add that `#include` directive: you don't need `std::endl` here, simply `'\n'` will suffice. As in the book...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how but my code is now running. I uninstalled the MinGW and then installed MinGW_w64. I suspect that my previous version of MinGW would not be compatible with my windows as it was maybe 32bit.
But afterall my code is now running good.